# Angular5 + CLI ng serve: background-image URL doesn't converted to base64

Tags: angular, angular5

Angular4 + cli@1.3.0

_variables.scss file contains:

```
$brand-logo: url('~assets/images/logo.png')
```

After 'ng serve' in style tag this image URL rebased to data:image/png;base64 and that's cool :)

---

Migrated to Angular5 + cli@1.6.4

Now I have an error when run 'ng serve' - fixed like described here https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/4778#issuecomment-280798718

_variables.scss file contains:

```
 $brand-logo: url('/assets/images/logo.png')
```

'ng serve' works fine, but inside style tag just URL to image
`background: url(/assets/images/logo.png);`
Maybe somebody knows how I can get rebased image code instead of file location?
Thanks to all

P.S.: sorry for my English